# Select query for independent columns

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I am trying to make Select query for independent columns.
If I would like to select student names per Class No. as below, How should I make the query..?

Class1   Class2   Class3

Lynn    Michael   Adrian

Teddy             Emily

Amy

(This is an example similar to the information I want to check)

I tried to make select query using sub-query per class No. however SQL error orruced and the message is 'Subquery returned more than 1 value'.

'

```
 SELECT 
 (SELECT A.NAME FROM STUDENT A WHERE A.CLASS_NO='1' AND A.PRSN_SQNO > 0),
 (SELECT A.NAME FROM STUDENT A WHERE A.CLASS_NO='2' AND A.PRSN_SQNO > 0),
 (SELECT A.NAME FROM STUDENT A WHERE A.CLASS_NO='3' AND A.PRSN_SQNO > 0),
 FROM STUDENT A
```

'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `case expressions`, like this:

```
 SELECT 
      CASE WHEN A.CLASS_NO='1' AND A.PRSN_SQNO > 0 THEN A.NAME END as Class1
    , CASE WHEN A.CLASS_NO='2' AND A.PRSN_SQNO > 0 THEN A.NAME END as Class2
    , CASE WHEN A.CLASS_NO='3' AND A.PRSN_SQNO > 0 THEN A.NAME END as Class3
 FROM STUDENT A
```

You don't need a full subquery for those columns, you already selecting from the student table. Instead, a case expression will evaluate the data available in the current row. Here you can control which column the value of `name` should appear in based on the values of `class_no` and `prsn_sqno` of that row.

Regarding your error message think of the result from a SQL query being a grid and in each cell there can only be a single value

```
      |  cola   |  colb   |  colc   |
1 row |  value  |  value  |  value  |
```

Now think about this query:

```
SELECT A.NAME FROM STUDENT A WHERE A.CLASS_NO='1' AND A.PRSN_SQNO > 0
```

This query will produce as many rows as there are students in class 1 and if that query is running as a subquery then you get that message **"Subquery returned more than 1 value"**

```
      |      cola     |      colb     |      colc     |
1 row |  (many rows)  |  (many rows)  |  (many rows)  |
```

That is, you are asking for many rows when there can only be a single value for a single row.